# How to select a specific element using the XPath function local-name() in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the element where `ext:tree-node-id="A"`

I have tried the following xpath: `//*[local-name()='tree-node-id' and text()='A']`  but it results in no matching nodes.

I have also tried to select all elements with the attribute:  ext:tree-node-id but no results were returned.

```
//*[local-name()='tree-node-id']    
.//*[local-name()='tree-node-id']  

//*[local-name()='ext:tree-node-id'] 
.//*[local-name()='ext:tree-node-id']
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks 
See xml

```html
<li class="x-tree-node">
    <div class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-selected x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="A">
        <span class="x-tree-node-indent">
        <img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <img class="x-tree-node-icon creditGroupAdd_ico" unselectable="on" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
    </div>
</li>
<li class="x-tree-node">
    <div class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-selected x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="B>
        <span class="x-tree-node-indent">
        <img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <img class="x-tree-node-icon creditGroupAdd_ico" unselectable="on" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
    </div>
</li>
<li class="x-tree-node">
    <div class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable x-tree-selected x-tree-node-expanded" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="C>
        <span class="x-tree-node-indent">
        <img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end-minus" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <img class="x-tree-node-icon creditGroupAdd_ico" unselectable="on" src="img-ext/s.gif"/>
        <a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole tag of the element? From what I see, this should work: //*[@ext:tree-node-id='A']

Comment: It didn't work.  I should mention that because i new to this i have been using FirePath to test the xpath

Answer (score 1):

You have *attribute* in namespace, not *element*. So it should be `@*` instead of just `*`. For example, following xpath select `<div>` element where `ext:tree-node-id` attribute value equals `"A"` :

```
.//div[@*[local-name()='tree-node-id' and .='A']]
```

Comment: it didn't work, i also tried .//*[@*[local-name()='tree-node-id'  and .= 'A']]

Comment: Is there another way of getting same information without using local-name().  I'm wondering maybe local-name doesnt work with firepath/firefox

Comment: Not sure, worked for me in an xpath tester. I'd suggest to isolate the problem to the smallest bit of xpath, try if it work without evaluating the attribute value : `//*[@*[local-name()='tree-node-id']]`

Answer (score 0):

//div[@ext:tree-node-id='A']

Mind trying this. Not sure how it will react with the ":". Though it worked on my end.

Comment: it comes up as  invalid xpath

Comment: FirePath does not seem to like the colon. Whenever i try it with the colon it complains its an  invalid xpath.  Not sure if this is a problem with firepath but since the broswer i will be testing is firefox i'm stuck with it

Comment: Aye. Made a test document with the current code. I'm not sure if the : <- messes it up. When i use //div[@unselectable='on'] it has no problems finding this.

Comment: //div[@*[local-name()='ext:tree-node-id' and .='A']]

This one worked for me. Try it out.

Comment: //div[@*[local-name()='ext:tree-node-id' and .='A']] worked.  Thanks all